# How to read Elastic APM configuration from Environment Variables in dotnet 6+

Tags: c#, .net, docker, elasticsearch, apm

Currently I have a dockerized WebAPI using DotNet 6 with the minimal API syntax. I have the following `appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Elastic.Apm": "Trace",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ElasticApm": {
    "ServerUrls": "http://host.docker.internal:8200",
    "CaptureBody": "all",
    "CaptureBodyContentTypes": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded*, text/*, application/json*, application/xml*",
    "CloudProvider": "none",
    "ServiceName": "MyApp"
  }
}
```

and use it like this in my `Program.cs`:

```
...
app.UseOpenApi();
app.UseSwaggerUi3();
app.UseReDoc();

app.UseAllElasticApm(app.Configuration);

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

However, I want to pass the configuration for Elastic APM as Environment Variables.

I expect there to be some sort of way to pass configuration in any other way than `appsettings.json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way to achieve this is to create a new ConfigurationBuilder like this:

```
...
// Setting environment variables here for readability
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ELASTIC_APM_SERVER_URLS", "http://host.docker.internal:8200");
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ELASTIC_APM_ENVIRONMENT", "dev");
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ELASTIC_APM_SERVICE_NAME", "MyApp");

var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()                    // Add Environment Variables to configuration 
    .Build();
app.UseAllElasticApm(config);

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

So my takeaway is that I did not understand well enough how exactly the minimal API syntax works.
This way you can also use other ways such as an `.env` file to read the config from.
These are all the Environment variables for APM:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/dotnet/current/config-all-options-summary.html

In summary, everything was in the docs and if you are well versed in dotnet it may be obvious, but to me it wasn't...

Comment: Apm will check environment variables by default if no configuration is passed as a parameter - so you don't actually need to call .AddEnvironmentVariables() - you can just use app.UseAllElasticApm() without the config.

Comment: oh that's neat, thanks for the info!